# Langkawi - can I snorkel wherever I want?

Tags: malaysia, outdoor-activities

I have my own snorkeling gear, but does that mean I have free-rein when it comes to where I can snorkel? Like, can I choose anywhere or are there certain places that are off-limits?

My line of thinking was that I could get away from the overly touristy snorkeling areas. If I have my own equipment, then I could choose any place that looked fun -- not just the areas on Langkawi that had dedicated snorkeling accommodations. I just want to make sure my rationale is correct before I get my hopes up.

Comment: AFAIK like in many places in Malaysia *all* the beaches are open access and public (although waterfront hotels might claim otherwise), with the exception of conservation area's / national parks / security zones. I think that for instance  Pulau Payar Marine Park requires that you buy a permit and pay a conservation charge (which will typically be included in the boat operators packages) .